# Is it possible to add new field dynamicaly through django admin panel

Tags: python, django, encryption, hash

I am still newbie to django. I have used a django admin. Now I want two things to do.

1.I need a model filed which will store as hash of raw data (something like password, but I want to assign my own encryption type & raw data should display when typing).

2.Admin User can add another field through a link something call 'add another field'.

For above two question, I need to know how save button works(let's say for add user page or a model add new row page) & where this page file is situated? Then how can I customize that page function. I know & use custom template(.html) page.

I found so many question related to this, but got complex to understand for newbie like me. I read django documentation for customizing password, but cann't able know, where to apply.

I have a model(which is display in admin site) like this model.py

```
class departments(models.Model):
  priority = models.TextField('prioriy') 
  department = models.TextField('Department')
  emp = models.IntegerField('Emp_id')
  empname = models.TextField('EmpName')
  def __unicode__(self):
    return department
```

I want emp field to hash encrypted & admin user can add more field. If possible, please describe briefly.Here is some more details..

First I want a custom save option for inserting raw value as hash data. like I have a field 'emp', When admin user enter raw data in that field, it should store hash encryption in model not direct row data.(inspired by password style).

Second, after that I can think the need of extra new field e.g. want to add

```
emp_father_name = models.TextField('Emp_father_Name')
```

I can think, I have to use ModelAdmin, but how & where. Is it something like use custom template.

Hope Now I am able to express it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any problem with question, or you need to know more information. Please let me know.. I am awaiting for any suggestion, as I cann't able to understand where to start.. Please give me a direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override save method in the models as below for hashing the field.

```
class departments(models.Model):
   priority = models.TextField('prioriy') 
   department = models.TextField('Department')
   emp = models.IntegerField('Emp_id')
   empname = models.TextField('EmpName')
   def __unicode__(self):
      return department

   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,      update_fields=None):
       self.emp = ur_hash_func(self.emp)
       return models.Model.save(self, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
```

This will hash your field.

I didn't understand the new extra feild part.

Comment: Thank you very much. 'new extra field' means, the admin user(a non programmer), who have the authority to change or add department model in admin site, wants have a feature of 'add another filed' in admin page.

Comment: Admin site generally manipulates the Model. When you say "who have the authority to change or add department model in admin site" does that mean you will link this new field to some other model(not departments)? If that is the case you can use inlines with custom method.

Comment: No no, It needs to add in department model. Because for now, he don't need that feature, but near future he may need.
The field of department model used to show in html table where (in future If some more field add) should be in a line.

Comment: I cann't use another inlines custom model, even if It has the feature of 'add'(it will add new row), I need a new field(column)

Comment: It is not a good idea to programmatically alter the database table structure. It might be disaster. Please think of some alternate way to implement your feature.

Answer (score 0):

> 2.Admin User can add another field through a link something call 'add another field'.

If i get clear. You can add new fields or sets like related objects from another model as in tutorials https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects